# Ubuntu 18 netplan Argument list too long

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, netplan

I try to add 8k IPs to my network interface with netplan, after adding all IPs to yaml netplan config and apply changes, i get the following error:
/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp5s0f0.network:1030: Failed to parse file: Argument list too long

it looks like at the moment netplan can't parse more than 1030 IPs, can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?